# How to define AOP pointcuts in Guice

Tags: java, aop, guice, aspectj

I am using Guice to intercept methods when they are marked with particular annotations:

```
@GuiceWillInterceptThis
public void doSomething() {
    // ...
}
```

As it turns out, most of the methods in this project are annotated with `@GuiceWillInterceptThis` and it is becoming annoying to keep tagging method-after-method with the same annotation just so Guice knows to intercept them.  It would be nice if I could somehow define "patterns" of methods to intercept.

For instance it would be nice to say "*intercept only methods returning type X inside class Y inside pakcage Z*".

I have done this before with Spring & AOP Alliance, where I defined "pointcuts" (I *think* that's the right AOP terminology!) in XML and Spring bootstrapped AOP Alliance to bind the right advice to all the joinpoints within those defined pointcuts, like so:

```
execution(public * *(..))
```

I would like to do the same (since Guice uses AOP Alliance as well) but without using Spring, and without using XML to define the pointcuts.

I have downloaded the AOP Alliance distribution and cant seem to figure out how to define pointcuts programmatically (in Java). Also, I wouldn't know where to add such code (maybe the Guice module?)

I have a feeling I may need to use AspectJ for such a thing, but I have zero experience with that and don't want to head down that road unless some learned folk on SO tell me that its my only option. (Which, by the way, if it is, maybe a kind soul could provide an ultra-quick code snippet to show how one would accomplish this in AspectJ?!?!)

Thanks in advance for any nudges in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement [`com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/matcher/Matcher.html) interface for both class and method matching and use it in [`bindInterceptor`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#bindInterceptor%28com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%3E,%20com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.reflect.Method%3E,%20org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor...%29) within module configuration.